# Ajax filter for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, taxonomy

after a lot of research i came across this: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/ajax-post-filters.html

But I can only get it to work when there are two options selected.

I'll give you some context:
I have a CPT named 'Contratistas' that has two custom taxonomies 'especialidad' and 'industria', they both have two terms each 'especialidad' -> 'tecnologia' and 'auditoria'; 'industria' -> 'cultivo' and 'depocito'

here is my function:

```js
function misha_filter_function(){
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date', // we will sort posts by date
        'order' => $_POST['date'], // ASC or DESC
        'post_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'contratista'
    );
    // for taxonomies / categories
    if( isset( $_POST['filtroEspecialidad'] ) && isset ($_POST['filtroIndustria'])  ) {
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
         //'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'especialidad',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['filtroEspecialidad']
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'industria',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['filtroIndustria']
            ),
        );
    
    } elseif( !isset($_POST['filtroEspecialidad'] ) && isset($_POST['filtroIndustria'])  ) {
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'industria',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['filtroIndustria']
        );
    
    } elseif( isset( $_POST['filtroEspecialidad'] ) && !isset($_POST['filtroIndustria'])  ) {
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'especialidad',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['filtroEspecialidad']
        );
    }
```

It works if you select something from both taxonomies, but when one is empty it says 'there are no post'

as a bonus I will like to show all the post before filtering.

I hope somebody can help me! Thanks! I'm fairly new to Wordpress

EDIT! Here is my js and my form, i'm at a loss here I can't figure out what's wrong :(

```js
jQuery(function($){
    $('#filter').submit(function(){
        var filter = $('#filter');
        $.ajax({
            url:filter.attr('action'),
            data:filter.serialize(), // form data
            type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                filter.find('.filtrar').text('Procesando...'); // changing the button label
            },
            success:function(data){
                filter.find('.filtrar').text('Filtrar'); // changing the button label back
                $('#response').html(data); // insert data
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

my php file:

```js
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
                    <div class="titulo mb-3">
                        <h3>Especialidad</h3>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                        if( $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'especialidad', 'orderby' => 'name' ) ) ) : 
                 
                            echo '<select name="filtroEspecialidad"><option value="">Seleccione una especialidad...</option>';
                            foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
                                echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>'; // ID of the category as the value of an option
                            endforeach;
                            echo '</select>';
                        endif;
                        
                    ?>
                    <div class="titulo my-3">
                        <h3>Industrias</h3>
                    </div>
                    <?php   
                        if( $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'industria', 'orderby' => 'name' ) ) ) : 
                 
                            echo '<select name="filtroIndustria"><option value="">Seleccione una industria...</option>';
                            foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
                                echo '<option  value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>'; // ID of the category as the value of an option
                            endforeach;
                            echo '</select>';
                        endif;
                    ?>  
                    <button class="my-3 filtrar">Filtrar</button>
                    <a href="" id="clear">Clear</a>
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to give the [Taxonomy Parameters of `WP_Query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) another glance. Unfortunately, WordPress is a little loose with it's `id` parameter names contextually. I'm not entirely sure your initial "both" is working like you intend either, because `'field' => 'id'` is actually invalid.

From the docs:

> field (string) – Select taxonomy term by. Possible values are `term_id`, `name`, `slug` or `term_taxonomy_id`. Default value is `term_id`.

`id` isn't actually a valid option. If you're just using the `term_id`, you should be able to omit that. You can also just programatically add the `tax_query` array arguments based on if that filter is set, instead of checking for "`both set`, `this set/that unset`, `this unset, that set`", something like this perhaps?

```
function misha_filter_function(){
    $args = array(
        'orderby'       => 'date', // we will sort posts by date
        'order'         => $_POST['date'], // ASC or DESC
        'post_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'contratista'
    );

    if( isset($_POST['filtroEspecialidad']) || isset($_POST['filtroIndustria']) ){
        $args['tax_query'] = array();
        
        if( isset($_POST['filtroEspecialidad']) ){
            $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'especialidad',
                'terms'    => $_POST['filtroEspecialidad']
            );
        }
        
        if( isset($_POST['filtroIndustria']) ){
            $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'industria',
                'terms'    => $_POST['filtroIndustria']
            );
        }

        if( count($args['tax_query']) > 1 ){
            $args['tax_query']['relation'] = 'AND';
        }
    }

    // Run WP_Query with new $args, etc.
}
```

I'm not sure if the `$_POST` values are arrays or single numbers, but you may want to validate those with `array_map` and/or `absint` if you're using user-supplied input, but if they're just IDs, the above should work for now.

Comment: This makes a lot of sence and is a better use of the code, but it still only works when both 'especialidad' and 'industria' are selected, but I think THIS is the way, so i'll work with it!! Thank you!! (Do you know how can I display all the post before filtering?)

Comment: Unfortunately if the above didn't work (it should) there may be something else at play, especially depending on how/when you're calling the function, whether it's modifying/replacing the main query or not, whether the $_POST['filtro…'] variables are being sent as blank strings, etc (check to make sure they aren't being sent if not picked). Re: Display Before, again that depends on what the original page query looks like on your particular site

Comment: I've updated my code! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: the `.serialize()` function passes along empty values. You could try replacing `data:filter.serialize(),` with `data: $('#filter :input').filter(function(index, element) { return $(element).val() != ''; }).serialize(),` to strip out empty values and/or use `empty($_POST['filter_name_here'])` instead of `isset()`

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! IT WORKS!!! You gave me a lot of topics to learn! (I tried the 'empty' approach, now i'll check the other one!)

Comment: You're welcome! Generally speaking, it's more important on the processing/validation side (so using `empty()` should be sufficient), but sending "as little data as necessary over the wire" is a good practice to follow too - so if you can get both working, great! If not, just using `empty()` should be good, especially in a "filter posts" scenario like this! Glad to help!